# How to skip calling the getter method when the lazy field was not loaded in mapstruct to avoid LazyInitializationException?

Tags: jpa, mapstruct

How to skip calling the getter method when the lazy field was not loaded in `mapstruct` mapper that map JPA entity to DTO?

I am using `JPA` EntityGraph to load required child entity for `method1` but `method2` I am using different EntityGraph and I don't want to create different mapper for every case.

Is there any way to create one mapper for both methods and ignore property that lazy loaded?

Comment: I don't think this is allowed, see https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1108 ,https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/778#issuecomment-209048276 and https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have two method who make the same mapping, and one where you ignore field that are not initialized

```
abstract Personne toDtoV1(PersonneModel model);

@Mapping(target = "nom", ignore = true)
abstract Personne toDtoV2(PersonneModel model);
```

or if you need only one methode, you create a mapping with all field who can be lazy loaded in ignore, and in a methode after mapping you check if relation is loaded and you make the mapping yourself

```
@Mapping(target = "nom", ignore = true)
abstract Personne toDtoV2(PersonneModel model);

@AfterMapping
void afterpersonneModel(PersonneModel dto, @MappingTarget Personne mode){
    //check if relation is loaded
    ///and make the mapping
}
```